# Piecewise linear knots and smooth knots

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

Is the set of all piecewise linear (PL) knots is a good approximation of the set of all 1D smooth knots embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Once I saw a theorem related to that but not able to find it now. Any help please?

UPDATE:

I discovered in a [draft](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/KFI.pdf) of Dr. Kauffman that Reidemeister first discovered that for tame links, PL-equivalence = ambient isotopy (on page 2 of Kauffman's note). I would like to know the exact paper of Reidemeister.

UPDATE:

This [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410329.pdf) by Dr. Kauffman hints that the source might be Knotentheorie by  K. REIDEMEISTER.